# Bash: Update a variable within a file

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I know this is a simple answer and I could probably keep digging around on Google before I stroll across the answer. But I am on a tight schedule and I was hoping for an easy response.

I need to update a variable in ifcfg-eth0 upon an installation. So in other words, this is what needs to happen:

The following variables need to change from:

```
ONBOOT=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
```

to

```
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
```

Thanks in advance!

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -i -e '/^ONBOOT=/s|.*|ONBOOT=yes|; /^BOOTPROTO=/s|.*|BOOTPROTO=static|' file
```

Also try:

```
sed -i -re 's|^(ONBOOT=).*|\1yes|; s|^(BOOTPROTO=).*|\1static|' file
```

Or

```
sed -i -e 's|^\(ONBOOT=\).*|\1yes|; s|^\(BOOTPROTO=\).*|\1static|' file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of something like this, which lets you define exactly what values you want to add in the file:

```
$ bootproto="static"
$ sed -r "s/(BOOTPROTO\s*=\s*).*/\1$bootproto/" file
ONBOOT=no
BOOTPROTO=static
```

And to make the two of them together:

```
$ onboot="yes"
$ bootproto="static"
$ sed -r -e "s/(ONBOOT\s*=\s*).*/\1$onboot/" -e "s/(BOOTPROTO\s*=\s*).*/\1$bootproto/" file
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
```

#### Explanation

- `(BOOTPROTO\s*=\s*).*` catches a group of text containing `BOOTPROTO` + any_number_of_spaces + `=` + any_number_of_spaces. Then, matches the rest of the text, that we want to remove. `\1$var` prints it back together with the given variable.
- `\s*` keeps the current spaces as they were and then replaces the same line changing the current text with the bash variable `$bootproto`.
- `-r` is used to catch groups with `()` instead of `\(` and `\)`.

---

To make it edit in place, use `sed -i.bak`. This will create a backup of the file, `file.bak`, and the `file` will be updated with the new content.

All together:

```
sed -ir -e "s/(ONBOOT\s*=\s*).*/\1$onboot/" -e "s/(BOOTPROTO\s*=\s*).*/\1$bootproto/" file
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight and explanation. I had already seen the first response and marked as the answer but cheers anyway.

Comment: @Chris good to read that. I am more than fulfilled if you could learn something from my answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The similar as the `sed` solutons with `perl`

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/(ONBOOT)=no/$1=yes/;s/(BOOTPROTO)=dhcp/$1=static/' files....
```