# about use sed Modify the file？

Tags: sed

I have a question about using sed to modify file. My file content:

```
<data-value name="WLS_INSTALL_DIR" value="/home/Oracle/wlserver_10.3">
```

I want to replace the content of field `value="/home/Oracle/wlserver_10.3"`

to get this result:

```
<data-value name="WLS_INSTALL_DIR" value="/u03/Middle_home/Oracle/wlserver_10.3">
```

I use `sed`:

```
sed "6 i/^value=/>/s/value=  />\(.*\)/value=\"\/u03\/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3"\" \/\  /u03/silent.xml
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash: Update a variable within a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268688/bash-update-a-variable-within-a-file)

Comment: Don't use regexes to parse and modifiy xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sed` script has a number of issues.

First off, anything that looks like `6istuff` will simply write everything after `i` ("insert") verbatim as a new line before the sixth line. (Some dialects require a newline after the `i` and will basically do nothing.)

Secondly, `^value=` does not match your input; it would only select a line starting with the string `value=` (the `^` metacharacter means beginning of line).

Thirdly, the `/>` in your subsitution regex terminates the substitution and so everything from `>` onwards is parsed as invalid flags for the substitution. I cannot see the purpose of this part, anyway; it doesn't match your data, and so the regex fails.

What remains after removing all these superfluous and erroneous details is a more or less useful `sed` script. (I assume the `6` to address only the sixth line of input is intentional, although you don't mention this in the question at all.) I have made some additional minor improvements, such as using `%` as the substitution delimiter and tightening the regex so that it only ever substitutes a double-quoted value.

```
sed '6s%value="[^"]*"%value="/u03/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3"%'  /u03/silent.xml
```

Better than `6` would perhaps be to identify the line with `/name="WLS_INSTALL_DIR"/`.

Still, as alluded to in a comment, the proper way to manipulate XML is with a dedicated tool such as [`xsltproc`](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed 's|/home|/u03/Middle_home|'
```